# How delete files in ASP.Net 5

Tags: c#, file-io, asp.net-core

I have to delete files from `wwwroot\images` programatically. Is there some kind of FileManager in ASP.Net 5 rc1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `System.IO` namespace by including it in your platform dependencies;

```
...
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.IO": "..." 
        }
    }
  },
...
```

And using [`File.Delete(pathToFile)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: .. or just call System.IO.File.Delete(pathToFile) (.NET Core 1.1 at least)